# Design Patterns - Abstract Factory - BombedMazeFactory

Tags: design-patterns, factory, abstract

I have a question regarding the Abstract Factory pattern sample code from the Design Patterns book.

The book presents a simplified and partial example of a maze game where there are walls and doors connecting rooms.

There is a basic MazeFactory class which has the following factory methods:

```
class MazeFactory {
public:
    MazeFactory();

    virtual Maze* MakeMaze() const { return new Maze; }
    virtual Wall* MakeWall() const { return new Wall; }
    virtual Room* MakeRoom(int n) const { return new Room(n); }
    virtual Door* MakeDoor(Room* r1, Room* r2) const {
        return new Door(r1, r2);
    }
}
```

The author(s) then define a specialisation of MazeFactory:

```
class BombedMazeFactory : public MazeFactory {
    BombedMazeFactory();

    virtual Room* MakeWall() const { return new BombedWall; }
    virtual Door* MakeRoom(int n) const { return new RoomWithABomb(n); }
};
```

I don't know exactly how RoomWithABomb should work but lets say it creates a room which has a 5% chance of containing a bomb and if you open a door which contains a bombed room you explode.

Now lets say the client creates their maze using the BombedMazeFactory class and they create some rooms. The rooms created are of type RoomWithABomb*, however the factory returns a Room*.

In order to implement some maze game logic I would assume you would need to check whether a room contains a bomb, but Room* has no knowledge about bombs. The only way we can find out if a room contains a bomb is to cast Room* to RoomWithABomb* which is bad practice right?

Is their example not very well thought out or is there some other way of handling cases such as this?

Comment: If each room had an Enter() method, this could be overridden in the RoomWithABomb subclass and have the logic for randomly setting off a bomb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is you don't need to know what kind of room it is.
Let's say `Room` is a class with a method `enter()` and when you enter the room maybe it prints out something. The class could look like this (I'll do this in Java since I'm not that familiar with C++, but you will get the idea):

```
public class Room {

   protected int roomNumber;

   public Room(int n) {
       roomNumber = n;
   }

   public void enter() {
       System.out.println("You entered room number " + roomNumber);
   }

   public void getRoomNumber() {
       return roomNumber;
   }
}
```

Now let's think about a room with a bomb. Obviously it is a derivative of `Room`, but it should print something out like "You exploded" instead.

```
public class RoomWithABomb extends Room {
    public RoomWithABomb(int n) {
       super(n);
    }

    public void enter() {
       System.out.println("Oh no! There was a bomb in the room! You died");
    }

}
```

So now our `RoomWithABomb` class overrides the behavior from the `Room` class (polymorphism!). A caller however, would not need to know exactly what kind of room is entered, because we know that every `Room` (and therefore also every `RoomWithABomb`, since it inherits from `Room`) has a `enter()` method.

So what is the intent of an abstract factory? We want to create similar objects, objects that inherit from a common super class or interface, so that other objects don't need to know how to create them. By doing this we also decouple other objects from the concrete implementations of said interface (the Maze doesn't even know that there is a room with a bomb).

Comment: I'm reasonable happy with this answer. I suppose enter() would need a MazeGame instance to change state of the game, which increases coupling but I can't see a good alternative.